# Components use different props

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, components, redux-thunk

If i use isLoggedIn() in componentDidMount of AuthLoadingScreen, actions works succesful but, i can not reach state.auth from another component, showing initial state.

Example as below:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { isLoggedIn } from '../src/actions/authActions'

class AuthLoadingScreen extends React.Component {  
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.isLoggedIn()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ActivityIndicator />
        <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, { isLoggedIn })(AuthLoadingScreen)
```

With this way state return as initial state on another component. Like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const { user } = state.auth

  return {
    user,
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {startChat, leaveChat, onSend})(Chat)
```

But if i put to under render function im reaching succesful from another component to same state.

```
  render() {
    this.props.isLoggedIn()
    ...
    ...
  }
```

-- Debugger screenshots --

[If i call isLoggedIn action below **render()** debugger like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYR0F.png)

[If i call isLoggedIn action below **componentDidMount()** debugger like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rm0Wh.png)

[type_login_success doesnt show in debugger's default instance. But if i change second instance as manuel shows here alone.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V61mp.png)

Another solution that works poorly is:

```
  componentDidMount(){
    setTimeout(()=>this.props.isLoggedIn(), 100)
  }
```

How can i use correctly? Sorry for my English. Thanks.

Comment: what does `isLoggedIn` do?

Comment: You can reach to isLoggedIn here: https://pastebin.com/TyTNu1yc

Dispatching to login types for save login data. But actually, it doesn't really matter what it does. If i clear function inside of isLoggedIn, still shifts to another instance (i described with photo) on debugger.